# wxPython: Assigning text labels to ticks on a slider

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

A wxPython program that I'm writing uses two sliders as part of the GUI. These sliders represent a three state switch with the states "On Full", "On Medium" and "Off". I'd like to be able to assign these labels to the ticks on the slider. Is there a way of doing this without having to subclass or position separate static text controls?

Thanks,
Spry

Answer (score 1):

Not built in. You'd have to create your own.